# How do I split up a list of data points into invervals and assign values to those intervals?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, linear-algebra

So I have a data set for chess and our goal is to plot the difference between the rating difference versus white's win rate. I want to subdivide the x-axis into intervals like  (-10, 0) (10,20) (20,30) and read the data in the intervals and get the percent of white's win rate over that inverval. Our goal is to plot sort of like a step function for each of the intervals and eventually create a linear regression with the values of each interval.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Can you give some example data that people could work with? This would be helpful in terms of getting an answer. Also useful is to show what code you have already tried

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) and [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) as follows:

First some fake win/loss and rating difference data:

```
SeedRandom[1]
whiteWinLoss = RandomInteger[1, 200];
ratingdiff = Subtract @@ RandomInteger[100, {2, 200}];
```

(1) Construct a `WeightedData` object using `whiteWinLoss` as weights

```
wd = WeightedData[ratingdiff, whiteWinLoss];
```

(2) Use `Histogram` with bin width `10` and height spec `"Probability"`:

```
Histogram[wd, {10}, "Probability"]
```

[image]